# Picker function in Xamarin not showing items

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dropdown

Here is my code.

```
List<DriverStatusViewModel> driverStatus = PopulateDriverStatus();
            var selectedStatus = driverStatus.FirstOrDefault();

            var picker = new Picker { Title = "Select a status" };
            picker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, "driverStatus");
            picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "selectedStatus");
            picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Status");
```

Populate the List

```
private List<DriverStatusViewModel> PopulateDriverStatus()
        {
            var driverStatus = new List<DriverStatusViewModel>();
            var stat1 = new DriverStatusViewModel();
            stat1.EnumId = 1;
            stat1.Status = "At Lunch";
            driverStatus.Add(stat1);
            var stat2 = new DriverStatusViewModel();
            stat2.EnumId = 2;
            stat2.Status = "Break";
            driverStatus.Add(stat2);
            var stat3 = new DriverStatusViewModel();
            stat3.EnumId = 3;
            stat3.Status = "Delivering";
            driverStatus.Add(stat3);
            return driverStatus;
        }
```

Xaml codes for display

```
<Picker Title="Select a status"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding driverStatus}"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding selectedStatus}" />
```

Below image is how it looks like when running in emulator
[image]

Im very new to Xamarin, Please help me and Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're not setting the Name property on any of the drivers?

Comment: do you set the ItemsSource correctly?

Comment: In your code you're creating a new picker, different from the one in your XAML. You need to set a name for your picker in xaml, by defining `x:Name="myPicker"` then you can access is from code using `myPicker.ItemsSource = driverStatus;`

Comment: driverStatus should be a property with getter and setter: List<DriverStatusViewModel> DriverStatus {get;set;}

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT actually I have different ways in solving it. Thank you for your time and helping me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post an answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In Xaml, add `x:Name="pic"`:

```
<Picker Title="Select a monkey" 
        TextColor="Black"
        x:Name="pic"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding selectedStatus}"/>
```

In your page add:

```
pic.ItemsSource = driverStatus;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you set a `Binding` in code, the `string` cannot "point" to a local variable. The binding is evaluated at runtime, so there would have to be a property with the name `driverStatus` and `selectedDriver` in the view model.

So instead of setting it as a local variable, create two properties `DriverStatus` and `SelectedDriver` and bind to them. Also you probably want to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the UI is notified when the property values change.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve the Picker.

//ViewModel

```
public class DriverStatusViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<DriverStatus> statusList;
        public List<DriverStatus> StatusList
        {
            get { return statusList; }
            set
            {
                if (statusList != value)
                {
                    statusList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        DriverStatus selectedStatus;
        public DriverStatus SelectedStatus
        {
            get { return selectedStatus; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedStatus != value)
                {
                    selectedStatus = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

//Model

```
public class DriverStatus
    {
        public int E_Id { get; set; }
        public string E_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

//cs file

```
BindingContext = new DriverStatusViewModel
            {
                StatusList = PopulateDriverStatus()
            };
```

//adding Static data for DriverStatus

```
private List<DriverStatus> PopulateDriverStatus()
        {
            var driverStatus = new List<DriverStatus>();
            var stat1 = new DriverStatus();
            stat1.E_Id = 1;
            stat1.E_Name = "At Lunch";
            driverStatus.Add(stat1);
            var stat2 = new DriverStatus();
            stat2.E_Id = 2;
            stat2.E_Name = "Break";
            driverStatus.Add(stat2);
            var stat3 = new DriverStatus();
            stat3.E_Id = 3;
            stat3.E_Name = "Delivering";
            driverStatus.Add(stat3);
            return driverStatus;
        }
```

//XAML file

```
<Picker x:Name="picker" 
     Title="Select new status"
     TextColor="Black"
     HorizontalOptions="Start"
     ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding E_Name}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}"/>

<Label Text="{Binding SelectedStatus.E_Id}" IsVisible="False" x:Name="E_Id"/>
```

Special thanks to this answer [Xamarin Forms Picker Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849856/xamarin-forms-picker-binding/45854313#45854313) I followed what he did.